# How to get footnote rule and footnote text to follow text color in `tcolorbox`?

Tags: color, footnotes, tcolorbox, text, footmisc

I am trying to get the footnote rule and footnote text to follow the color of the text in the `tcolorbox`. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,abovefloats]{footmisc} % footnotes
\colorlet{textcolor}{Maroon}
\colorlet{framecolor}{Maroon!90!white}
\colorlet{bgcolor}{MistyRose}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=bgcolor,coltext=textcolor,%
colframe=framecolor,top=1pt,title=Colorbox]
This is colored text within the colorbox\footnote{How do I get the footnote rule and the footnote text to follow the textcolor?}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

How might I accomplish that?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black color of footnote inside a `tcolorbox` environment inherits from `minipage` environment, for which a `\normalcolor` is used in `\endminipage` just before typesetting the footnote (including the footnote line).

`\normalcolor` uses `\default@color`, the "current color" at begin document, as the current color.  That's how [@samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682332) works: locally overwrite `\default@color`.  Note applying this change, effect of `\normalcolor` used in other places (e.g., equation tags) inside `tcolorbox` env are canceled as well.  Perhaps this side effect is exactly what OP expect, perhaps not.

Here's another way that alters color of footnote in `tcolorbox` environment only.  It removes the `\normalcolor` from not `\endminipage`, but a `tcolorbox` alias `\endtcb@lrbox` (defined by `\let\endtcb@lrbox=\endminipage`).  For breakable boxes, the command to patch is `\endtcb@vbox`.  The patching relies on how `\endminipage` is defined, hence could be tricker than @samcarter's answer.

- The [`/.try`](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#handlers/.try) used in following example is a `pgfkeys` key handler. It's used here to make the example compile both with or without `tcolorbox` library `breakable`.  (`breakable/.try` means, if `breakable` is defined use it, otherwise ignore it.)  In non-test documents one can safely remove `/.try`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage[margin=.3in, noheadfoot, paperheight=12cm, paperwidth=15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\let\endtcb@lrbox@normal=\endtcb@lrbox
\let\endtcb@lrbox@footnoteinheritcolor=\endtcb@lrbox
\xpatchcmd\endtcb@lrbox@footnoteinheritcolor
  {\normalcolor}
  {\iftcb@hasLower\color{tcbcollower}\else\color{tcbcolupper}\fi}
  {}{\PatchFailed}

% if breakable library is loaded, patch \endtcb@vbox too
\ifdefined\endtcb@vbox
  \let\endtcb@vbox@normal=\endtcb@vbox
  \let\endtcb@vbox@footnoteinheritcolor=\endtcb@vbox
  \xpatchcmd\endtcb@vbox@footnoteinheritcolor
    {\normalcolor}
    {\iftcb@hasLower\color{tcbcollower}\else\color{tcbcolupper}\fi}
    {}{\PatchFailed}
  \def\tcb@footnote@normalcolor{%
    \let\endtcb@lrbox=\endtcb@lrbox@normal
    \let\endtcb@vbox=\endtcb@vbox@normal
  }
  \def\tcb@footnote@inheritcolor{%
    \let\endtcb@lrbox=\endtcb@lrbox@footnoteinheritcolor
    \let\endtcb@vbox=\endtcb@vbox@footnoteinheritcolor
  }
\else
  \def\tcb@footnote@normalcolor{%
    \let\endtcb@lrbox=\endtcb@lrbox@normal
  }
  \def\tcb@footnote@inheritcolor{%
    \let\endtcb@lrbox=\endtcb@lrbox@footnoteinheritcolor
  }
\fi

\tcbset{
  footnote inherit color/.is choice,
  footnote inherit color/true/.code={%
    \let\endtcb@lrbox=\endtcb@lrbox@footnoteinheritcolor
    \let\endtcb@vbox=\endtcb@vbox@footnoteinheritcolor
  },
  footnote inherit color/false/.code={%
    \let\endtcb@lrbox=\endtcb@lrbox@normal
    \let\endtcb@vbox=\endtcb@vbox@normal
  },
  footnote inherit color/.default=true
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title={\texttt{footnote inherit color=false}, default behavior},
  colupper=blue!70!black,
  collower=red!70!black
]
  Upper part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed
  \tcblower
  Lower part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title={\texttt{footnote inherit color=true}},
  colupper=blue!70!black,
  collower=red!70!black,
  footnote inherit color
]
  Upper part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed
  \tcblower
  Lower part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title={\texttt{footnote inherit color=true}, broken at upper part},
  colupper=blue!70!black,
  collower=red!70!black,
  breakable/.try,
  use color stack/.try,
  footnote inherit color
]
  Upper part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed\par
  \lipsum[1][1-6]\par
  Broken upper part\footnote{text}.
  \tcblower
  Lower part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  title={\texttt{footnote inherit color=true}, broken at lower part},
  colupper=blue!70!black,
  collower=red!70!black,
  breakable/.try,
  use color stack/.try,
  footnote inherit color
]
  Upper part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed\par
  \tcblower
  Lower part\footnote{text}. \color{gray!50}color changed\par
  \lipsum[1][1-5]\footnote{text}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand what `breakable` and `try` mean, but what you have done works for my use cases.

Comment: @chandra `breakable` is a `tcolorbox` option provided by library `breakable`. You can check out the package doc for more info.  `/.try` is used only for testing and I've added a note for it.

Answer (score 2):

Quick hack: change `\default@color` to match the colour of your text:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,abovefloats]{footmisc} % footnotes
\colorlet{textcolor}{Maroon}
\colorlet{framecolor}{Maroon!90!white}
\colorlet{bgcolor}{MistyRose}

\makeatletter
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  before upper={\let\default@color\current@color},
  before lower={\let\default@color\current@color}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=bgcolor,
  coltext=textcolor,
  colframe=framecolor,
  top=1pt,
  title=Colorbox
]
This is colored text within the colorbox\footnote{How do I get the footnote rule and the footnote text to follow the textcolor?}.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One may also need `before lower={\let\default@color\current@color}` if the footnote appears in lower part of a `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Good point! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start point (not the best one though) but it works, and if you play around with some numbers you can get better, for your taste results:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,abovefloats]{footmisc} % footnotes
\colorlet{textcolor}{Maroon}
\colorlet{framecolor}{Maroon!90!white}
\colorlet{bgcolor}{MistyRose}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\color{textcolor} \arabic{mpfootnote}}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace{-5mm}\color{textcolor}\rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vspace{1mm}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=bgcolor,coltext=textcolor,%
        colframe=framecolor,top=1pt,title=Colorbox]
        This is colored text within the colorbox\footnote{\color{textcolor} How do I get the footnote rule and the footnote text to follow the textcolor?}.
        This is colored text within the colorbox\footnote{\color{textcolor} How do I get the footnote rule and the footnote text to follow the textcolor?}.
        This is colored text within the colorbox\footnote{\color{textcolor} How do I get the footnote rule and the footnote text to follow the textcolor?}.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```